# Compute upper and lower integral of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to solve the question in which they ask me to

> Compute upper and lower integrals for the function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [a,c)$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [c,b]$.

The thing stopping me from making progress is that when I extend the upper and lower Darboux sums for a standard partition $\sigma= \{a=x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n=b \}$ of $[a,b]$, I can't compute anything for any general interval of the form $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ with $i\in \{ 0,1,...,n-1 \}$ because I don't know their relation against $[a,c),[c,b]$.

Meaning that such interval can include points of both of them, or points of either one of them. The exercise comes from page 141 of the book "A First Course in Real Analysis by Sterling K. Berberian". Any hint is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Are you expected to find them using the definition? Because a "cheat" way would be to observe that the function is Riemann integrable, and therefore Darboux integrable, and both lower and upper Darboux integrals are equal to its (definite) Riemann integral.

Comment: I think what they expect of me is to find something somewhat general, because for the first part (I didn't write it here because I am satisfied with the answer I came up with) they ask the same but for a function that is equal to 1 in a point c between a and b, and equal to zero for the rest of points. So computing the upper and lower sums I could infer that the lower integral was gonna be equal to zero no matter the partition and the upper integral was always gonna be greater or equal to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any "standard" partition $(x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ there is an index $p$ such that $x_p \leqslant c < x_{p+1}$ and the upper and lower Darboux sums are

$$U(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]} f(x) \,(x_j - x_{j-1}) = 1 \cdot (b- x_p) = 1 \cdot (b - c +c - x_p) \\= b-c + (c - x_p) \leqslant  b- c + (x_{p+1} - x_p) \leqslant b-c + \|P\|$$

and

$$L(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]} f(x) \,(x_j - x_{j-1}) = 1 \cdot (b- x_{p+1}) = 1 \cdot (b - c + c - x_{p+1}) \\= b-c - (x_{p+1} -c) \geqslant b-c -(x_{p+1} - x_p) \geqslant b- c - \|P\|$$

where $\|P\|$ is the partition norm. Thus, for any partition $P$

$$b-c \leqslant U(P,f) \leqslant b-c +\|P\|, \\ b-c - \|P\|\leqslant L(P,f) \leqslant b-c  $$

Since the upper and lower sums are bounded below and above, respectively, the upper and lower integrals exist with

$$b-c \leqslant \overline{\int}_a^b f = \inf_{P'} U(P',f) \leqslant U(P,f) \leqslant b-c + \|P\|, \\ b-c - \|P\| \leqslant L(P,f) \leqslant \sup_{P'} L(P',f) = \underline{\int}_a^b f \leqslant b-c $$

For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose a partition $P$ with $\|P\| = \epsilon$ and we have

$$b-c - \epsilon \leqslant \underline{\int}_a^b f \leqslant \overline{\int}_a^b f \leqslant b-c + \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily close to $0$ it follows that

$$ \underline{\int}_a^b f = \overline{\int}_a^b f = b-c $$